# Could not import module

Tags: python, import

```
├── project
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── script.py
```

In `models.py` I have some classes, let's say Class1, Class2, Class3...
I can easily import these classes from `models.py` to `forms.py` using `from app.models import Class1, Class2, ...`.

When `script.py` runs I can't import these classes to `script.py` this way. Have `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'` (in `script.py`) When I use `from models import Class1, Class2, ...` have the same error, but in `models.py`. If it's important `models.py` is genereted by Django, `forms.py` is created by me. This is strange for me because `models.py` and `forms.py` can recognize `app` module and `script.py` can't, but all these files are placed in one directory. Copy-pasted imports, this is not misprint.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this setup I'd usually do something like this:

`script.py` being the main script would be in the project directory, next to app.

`init.py` would contain:

```
from app import models, forms
```

`script.py` would have

```
import app
```

If `models.py` needs anything in `forms.py`:

```
try:
    import forms # uses this when ran in models.py
except:
    from app import forms # uses this when ran from script.py
```

If `forms.py` needs anything in `models.py`:

```
try:
    import models # uses this when ran in forms.py
except:
    from app import models # uses this when ran from script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're executing `python script.py`, move it to outside the `app` module.

Comment: Is it possible to run in the module?

Comment: I believe if every import in the module is relative, then yes.